# How would you do a code-escape in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I have a huge list of stuff for a glossary ( about 17 pages worth ) that I have to put into an XML file. So I decided I'd use php to make it. My code works, except where ALL the XML code is, it doesn't show because it's trying to render it. Help?

```
        $arg=explode("\n", $strang);
        echo count($arg);
        for ($i=0;$i<=count($arg);$i=$i+3)
        {
            echo "<word id='" . $arg[$i+1] . "'>";
            echo "<desc>" . $arg[$i] . " - " . $arg[$i+2] . "</desc>";
            echo "<pic></pic>";
            echo "<audio></audio>";
        }
```

Comment: you want the XML tags visible in a browser?

Comment: Render it? I assume that you mean that the browser attempts to parse your XML as HTML. You should use an XML header if you want a machine to parse your XML. If you want humans to read it in their browser, you can convert HTML characters by using http://php.net/htmlentities

Comment: @oblig yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by render it you mean in your browser? If so, you'll need to escape the characters so they will be interpreted literally rather than as markup.

Check out `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlentities`

Answer (score 0):

use CDATA construction:

```
echo "<desc><![CDATA[" . $arg[$i] . " - " . $arg[$i+2] . "]]></desc>";
```

Comment: Or you may use escaping like htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 0):

If this is your entire script, fastest way would probably be to swap all of the <'s with `&lt;`

```
    $arg=explode("\n", $strang);
    echo count($arg);
    for ($i=0;$i<=count($arg);$i=$i+3)
    {
        echo "&lt;word id='" . $arg[$i+1] . "'>";
        echo "&lt;desc>" . $arg[$i] . " - " . $arg[$i+2] . "&lt;/desc>";
        echo "&lt;pic>&lt;/pic>";
        echo "&lt;audio>&lt;/audio>";
    }
```